# Question regarding the authentication against a Google Cloud API through a self-programmed Java-Programm

Tags: java, api, gcloud

I'm trying to call one of the Google Cloud APIs from my Java-Program. Therefore I copied following code from Googles documentation which you can find here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/roles/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A1000%2C%22view%22%3A%22BASIC%22%2C%22prettyPrint%22%3Atrue%7D

```
/*
 * BEFORE RUNNING:
 * ---------------
 * 1. If not already done, enable the Identity and Access Management (IAM) API
 *    and check the quota for your project at
 *    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iam
 * 2. This sample uses Application Default Credentials for authentication.
 *    If not already done, install the gcloud CLI from
 *    https://cloud.google.com/sdk and run
 *    `gcloud beta auth application-default login`.
 *    For more information, see
 *    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
 * 3. Install the Java client library on Maven or Gradle. Check installation
 *    instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client.
 *    On other build systems, you can add the jar files to your project from
 *    https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/iam/v1/java
 */
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.Iam;
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.model.ListRolesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.iam.v1.model.Role;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IamExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Iam iamService = createIamService();
    Iam.Roles.List request = iamService.roles().list();

    ListRolesResponse response;
    do {
      response = request.execute();
      if (response.getRoles() == null) {
        continue;
      }
      for (Role role : response.getRoles()) {
        // TODO: Change code below to process each `role` resource:
        System.out.println(role);
      }
      request.setPageToken(response.getNextPageToken());
    } while (response.getNextPageToken() != null);
  }

  public static Iam createIamService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential =
          credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }

    return new Iam.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-iamSample/0.1")
        .build();
  }
}
```

I've copied the exact same code from the website and followed the instructions with downloading the gcloud CLI and downloading the libaries. But everytime I try to run the code I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:211)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at IamExample.createIamService(IamExample.java:53)
    at IamExample.main(IamExample.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 5 more
```

In the error it says something about "OAuth2" and "Google Credentials", after googling this I found out that I might need to implement a JSON-File which is generated by Google Cloud and contains the credentials to authenticate against the Google Cloud. I now have such a file but I didn't find a way in the documentations how to link this file to my Java-Programm.
So is there maybe somebody who can tell me how to link the JSON-File to my Programm or how to fix the errors?

Comment: sounds like you are missing the bom in your pom https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/tree/main/google-api-client-bom